# PHP with sqlsrv_num_rows

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to execute a query of a SQL Server database, looking at a many to many relationship. I link the table I want the rows from with the relationship table, and plug in the unique id, in this case the $guid.

The query is functional, sometimes. It will work, and then I switch out solely the $guid for another one, and it fails, even though I'm staring at the table and it has values associated with that new $guid.

```
<?php
$guid = '{893C7BF8-E8C5-41D5-9C61-A72CF62DDBA8}';

// Connect to Database
$server = "#@#($#";     
$connectionSettings = array("Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pword");
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionSettings);

if (!$connection){
    die("Failed Connection");
}

// Prepare and Execute Query
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM STREAMS.ATTACHMENTS a INNER JOIN STREAMS.RELATTACHMENTS ra
        ON a.ROWGUID = ra.ATTACHMENT_GUID
        WHERE ra.FEATURE_GUID = '" . $guid . "'";

$results = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
$rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows( $results );

if ($rowCount === false)
    echo "failure";
else
    echo $rowCount;

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){
    echo "loop";
}
?>
```

Even stranger, the output to this code is the following:

```
failurelooploop
```

So that implies that the sqlsrv_num_rows command counted no rows in the result... but it also implies that the same results set has 2 rows, since the while loop went around twice.

Can anybody explain this funky behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I will bet that you have some sort of error: `sqlsrv_num_rows` will return `FALSE` if something goes wrong. You can get the error output through:

```
// probably don't want this in production.
print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
```

I'll guess the cause has to do with your `guid` column, but I can't be sure. :-)

Oh, and unless you need the number of rows, don't use it. Use `do... while` instead:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results);
if($row)
{
    do{
        echo "loop";
    } while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results ) );
}
else
{
    // No results found
    // you can output print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ); here
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -50 [code] => -50 [2] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. [message] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. ) ) 1looploop . /// Thats for the working GUID... now for the non working GUID I got the exact same error message but without the looploop at the end... does that suggest that both arrays have 0 elements? in the database they do have results from that query. I don't really understand the error.

Comment: Ok, so the reason that I was getting an error on the sqlsrv_num_rows was because I was using the default forward cursor, so thats fine, but it still doesn't explain the other behavior, the sql query only working for some GUIDS and not others... what could be wrong with the GUID column?

Comment: After 12 hours of searching... because of this post telling me to rid my sqlsrv_num_rows i was able to finally get my login script to work. I spend an entire day debugging my code only to find this post and it it working without effort! YIPEEEE...

Answer (score 1):

This error shows for cursor type SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD & SQLSRV_CURSOR_DYNAMIC . my personal preference is not to use it. if you still want to use it pass extra parameter to query function like :

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connection, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset' ));
// $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connection, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'dynamic' ));
// $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connection, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
```

check more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160.aspx
-- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php